# WCF / ASP.NET - protected against misuse such as DOS

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, wcf

We currently host a lengthy form on our ASP.NET website, which makes use of a public facing facade WCF service to submit information over SSL into our network through a number of other facade services, etc.

We've experienced some issues with downtime on the service chain, and because of this some users have been very frustrated that they complete the lengthy form, only to find out after the fact that the service isn't up. Because of this, we are implementing a type of ping functionality on the form that will ping the service before the form is started, to ensure the service is up.

If the `Ping()` method is simply called during `OnLoad` of the form web page, there is potential for DOS attacks through for example a script that continually makes HTTP GET requests against the page.

My question is - From a conceptual level, what is the best way to ensure human interaction with the page while keeping it useable. For example, a CAPTCHA before the `Ping()` is called and form is started is way too intrusive even though it would be effective at ensuring the form is used properly. On the other hand simply allowing `Ping()` to fire `OnLoad` is far too risky for attacks.

One option I've considered is to have a button available to users which allows them to verify service availability and enable the form in one shot. This would at least be a balance between the two. I'm asking for your input on ideas for how best to balance this approach. Any asp.net, c#, or javascript/ajax based answers are fine.

Lastly - I also know there are flaws to this approach of checking service availability as there is no guarantee the service will be available by the time the form is filled out - but the decision has been made to use this approach so please keep your answers on point.

Thanks for the help and input in advance!

**UPDATE 1:**

In response to Josh's answer below - I should clarify that the form data submitted is sensitive and cannot be cached on the server or stored locally for later submission if the service fails. This is why it is very important to give the user a preemptive heads up. The issues we've had with the services are not intermittent so if the `Ping()` comes back true, there is an extremely good chance the user will not experience issues submitting the form a few minutes later.

**UPDATE 2:**

- The `Ping()` Method is currently a server-side c# method, not javascript.
- The public facing WCF service is IP-restricted to only allow requests from the public web server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just call `Ping()` when the submit button is pressed and if the service doesn't respond then don't submit the form and show an error.

Something like this in jQuery. This assumses that `Ping()` returns `true` if the service is up, `false` otherwise:

```
$('#myformid').submit(function() {
  var svcUp = Ping();

  if(!svcUp)
      alert("Sorry, there was an error submitting, please try again.");

  return svcUp;
});
```

Unfortunately any public facing web service that has a low calling cost but high processing cost will be vulnerable to DOS attacks without some type of throttling.

Thankfully WCF has some useful settings for controlling throttling, take a look at [MaxConcurrentCalls](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.servicethrottlingelement.maxconcurrentcalls.aspx), [MaxConcurrentInstances](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.servicethrottlingelement.maxconcurrentinstances.aspx), and [MaxConcurrentSessions](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.servicethrottlingelement.maxconcurrentsessions.aspx)

Comment: This but expand upon it; make sure to use AJAX so the user doesn't lose any data and, if they have Html5 available, offer to save it locally for them or possibly send it to a back-up server or SOMETHING.

Comment: Thanks Josh for the input. The form already handles any issues through a number of FaultExceptions. They already get a user friendly error message. The problem comes back to they don't want to fill out the form in the first place if the service is unavailable...

Comment: He doesn't explicitly mention he is using jquery

Comment: In that case why not do the check server-side and just show a "Sorry the system is currently unavailable." instead of the form.

Comment: @josh: That is my goal, which I can do now. The problem is someone could easily write a script to make a million HTTP requests against the page, causing the server side `Ping()` method to get hammered. I do like the throttle control properties you pointed out. I will look at whether these are suitable. +1 for this so far...

Comment: Thanks Josh for your answer. While I already have a code check similar to what you suggest, I didn't consider using throttling attributes in the WCF service settings themselves.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no good solution on the client-side to prevent a DOS attack - I can create a script using your Ping js method that will call it a million times in a loop. You can prevent it on the server side though, by tracking calls per second form the same ip/session/user/otherclient-side identifier. If number of calls per second is over some reasonable limit, you temporarily ban that client.

You can look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/10ASPNetPerformance.aspx - scroll down to "Prevent Denial of Service (DOS) Attack" for an example

Answer (score 1):

Call your function on page load and prior to the submit button.  If you have any logging you are using you could insert into a log table for this particular aspx page view and include the IP address of the visitor.  Set a threshold and if the IP makes more requests than what you required as proper usage, then put up some type of human-validation item.

Comment: +1 Matt. I like your answer and it makes sense, but I think Josh's answer to use the built-in WCF throttle control mechanisms is simpler in my case.